# Migrating Laravel Passwords to Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.
Laravel uses the PHP `crypt` function. I'm not sure what the equivalent is in Ruby.
My passwords are hashed with a `$2a` hash as well, if that makes a difference.

This is Laravel's function

```
public static function check($value, $hash)
{   
    return crypt($value, $hash) === $hash;
}
```

I've tried Bcrypt::Password.new as well as String#crypt but I can't seem to get them to work.

Example password `$2a$08$WJZWRyljoJGx.qunOGuGLeDaOn/Q3ShEvGxTkx3csWXqWUF21GhBe` from the database and the real was `123456`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that. I just figured out how it worked after posting.

The solution was `BCrypt::Password.new('$2a$08$WJZWRyljoJGx.qunOGuGLeDaOn/Q3ShEvGxTkx3csWXqWUF21GhBe') == '123456'`

Answer (score 0):

The PHP crypt method uses a non-standard notation for bcrypt-hashed entries. You need to correct this:

```
hash = '$2y$10$tKrgxXzN.naFD3r//yX9/O5uJmGRA9lzlcoPgK.F8REX.kx9xOesS'
BCrypt::Password.new(hash.sub(/\A\$2y/, '$2a')) ==  "Test1111!"
# => true
```

There was a bug in PHP's crypto library so 2y represents the fixed version.